# Does svelte have built-in protection against updating a reactive variable in async operation when the component is unmounted

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, svelte

I have my `App` component set up like this. Only relevant code is shown for brevity.

```
// script
let view = 'products';

// markup
<sidebar/>
<view-container>
   {#if view === 'products'}
     <products />
   {:else if view === 'orders'}
     <orders />
   {/if}
<view-container>
```

In the `products.svelte` I have an `api` that fetches some data and assigns it a reactive variable.

```
//script
let data = [];
fetch(url).then(res => res.json()).then(json => {
  data = json; // just assume json is an array;
})

//markup
{#each data as entry (entry.id)}
  <product-card product_info={entry} />
{/each}
```

Given that I can switch between `products` and `orders` view with the `sidebar` really quickly. What will happen is the fetch call will be a bit late and the assignment to data variable will be after the `products` component has been destroyed. Is this cleanly handled by the library itself. Are those assignments just no-ops are real errors. If we consider an analogous scenario in react by setting state after the component there is an error.

I am aware of `onMount` and `onDestroy` hooks in svelte. I am very curious about this scenario. I can't find my answer about this from the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way changes to components work is:

- The component stores which values of its state have been changed
- It is marked as dirty and an update is scheduled
- When the update runs, all dirty components with a DOM "fragment" get their DOM updated

Destroying a component nulls out its fragment, hence simply nothing happens on update.

Answer (score 0):

If svelte does have support for this, its not easy to find in their docs.

The browser `fetch()` API does, however, allow an `AbortSignal` object instance which allows you to communicate with a given fetch request and abort it if desired.

With implementation of `AbortSignal`, you're second snippet might look somethin like this:

```
//script
import { onDestroy } from 'svelte';

const controller = new AbortController();
const signal = controller.signal;

let data = [];

fetch(url, { signal }).then(res => res.json()).then(json => {
  data = json; // just assume json is an array;
})

onDestroy(() => {
    controller.abort();
  });

//markup
{#each data as entry (entry.id)}
  <product-card product_info={entry} />
{/each}
```

[Read more about implementing an `AbortSignal` instance on the MDN docs, here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController/signal)

Hope this helps.